# Add internal code to Eav Attribute option?

Tags: magento2, attribute-options, eav-attributes

I am new to Magento 2.

All my data comes from an external db.
Before importing my products into Magento, I want to prepare the environment.

I am currently trying to set up custom EAV attributes with options that suit these products. I think I found how to manage this.

But there is something which I don't see how to handle.
Each EAV attribute option has a value assigned to it, ok.
But in my case, it's a bit tricky, I also need to set an internal alphanumeric code for each of these options.

I could put it in the value, together with the actual option value, but it would mean the internal code would be reflected in frontend views as well, which is not acceptable.

Could anyone suggest an approach which would help me with this brainshaking issue?

When I retrieve products from the external db, the options for each attribute are actually just the internal code and I will have to retrieve the actual option values from its related code.